# Is it possible to turn a string into a function object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter and matplotlib to create a small sorting array project. My Tkinter GUI has a listbox that I want to use to choose the desired sorting algorithm. I'm using matplotlib's FuncAnimation() to iterate repeatedly through my chosen sorting function and animate them. FuncAnimation() takes the name of the function that you decide to use as an argument. I wanted to assign the argument a variable that I could reassign to the name of any function that I wanted to use.

I believe the problem is that listbox.get(ANCHOR) gives me a string and FuncAnimation wants some sort of function object. I've looked into possible ways to a string into a function object or callable function but I'm either not understanding or not finding anything.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk


#example of one of the sorting functions.
def Quick_Sort(i):
global arr # I don't know why I have to use a globalized variable. Wouldn't let me pass it arr
n=len(arr)
less_than=[]
equal_to=[]
greater_than=[]
if i in range(1,n-1):
    if arr[i-1]>arr[i] or arr[i]>arr[i+1]:
        #break into sub arrays
        pivot=arr[i]
        del arr[i]
        for y in range(0,n-1):
            plt.clf()
            if arr[y]< pivot:
                less_than.append(arr[y])
            if arr[y]==pivot:
                equal_to.append(arr[y])
            elif arr[y]>pivot:
                greater_than.append(arr[y])
        del arr[:]
        less_than.append(pivot)
        arr=less_than + equal_to + greater_than
        del less_than[:], greater_than[:], equal_to[:]

        plt.bar(arr_ind,arr)
        fig.canvas.draw()
elif i>n-1:
    print("'i' is out of range. Exiting program.")
    print ("Final array is ", arr)
    sys.exit()
return i


def choose_and_run():
choice=listbox.get(ANCHOR)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
fill_array(arr,arr_ind,arr_size)
fig.canvas.draw()
anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,choice,interval=50)
plt.show()


#---TKINTER STUFF-------
window=tk.Tk()
window.title("Sorting Arrays")
window.geometry("150x00")

listbox=tk.Listbox(window)
# Algorithm Options
listbox.insert(1,"Bubble_Sort")
listbox.insert(2,"Insertion_Sort")
listbox.insert(3,"Quick_Sort")
listbox.insert(4,"Selection_Sort")
listbox.pack()

# Select and run button
button1=tk.Button(window,text="Get and Go",command=choose_and_run).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Hope this was enough information. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wouldn't normally convert a string to a function name directly, even if with Python just about anything's possible.  However, functions are just objects so just use a dict:

```
chosenfunc = {"Bubble_Sort":Bubble_Sort, "Insertion_Sort":Insertion_Sort,
               "Quick_Sort":Quick_Sort, "Selection_Sort":Selection_Sort}
selection=listbox.get(ANCHOR)
choice = chosenfunc[selection]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Didn't realize I could use a dict.

Comment: There's an added advantage is the GUI selection items don't have to match the function names they are calling.  So you can drop the underscores in the users' selections. (Just make sure you make the dict keys match!!)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `locals()` or `globals()` to get access to a dictionary with the local or global symbol table, respectively. You can use this if your functions are declared in the same module.

If not, you can use `getattr` on a module object:

```py
import module

dynamically_imported_method = getattr(module, 'bar')
dynamically_import_method()
```

Comment: I've done icky things like this to create function options just based on function names in the global dictionary.  It made adding new capabilities as simple as defining the function, but I think this is a bit more deep python than the question merits.   Maybe defining a class with all the functions defined within it, and using dir() on the class might be a little better.